# How can I change the font size?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can you help me? Here is a picture from my **Visual Studio Code**. I really don't know that.
[image]

Comment: you can look for the CSS selector for the menu and `inject css` with an extension to modify that tag

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there's currently no option which does only the menu bar. However, you can try adding this to your `vscode/settings.json`. The default value is `0`, it does accepts decimals.

```
"window.zoomLevel": 0.4
```